# Cucumber : Setting setSkippedAsNotFailing is not working when I am running from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Below are my Jenkins setup:

1. Created Freestyle project
2. In Build section added :- Invoke top-level Maven targets In
   [image]
3. In Post-Build Actions added:- Cucumber reports
   [image]
   [image]

However the same is working fine when I am executing from maven. here is  the pom.xml setting related to cucumber reports.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <projectName>Sample</projectName>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</inputDirectory>
                        <buildNumber>2</buildNumber>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</classificationDirectory>
                        <classificationFiles>
                            <param>*.properties</param>
                        </classificationFiles>
                       <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        <setSkippedAsNotFailing>true</setSkippedAsNotFailing>
                        <treatPendingAsFailed>false</treatPendingAsFailed>
                        <treatUndefinedAsFailed>false</treatUndefinedAsFailed>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Please let ne know what I am missing..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [cucumber-reports-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin) does not have a setting for its own **notFailingStatuses** parameter(aka setSkippedAsNotFailing in pom) from [cucumber-reporting](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting) library.

I have forked the plugin and made some changes to enable that setting. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/danny-briskin/cucumber-reports-plugin) and build a custom plugin yourself.